# jQuery.ajax() - How to handle timeouts best?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling, timeout

I'm wondering, what's the best way to handle timeouts with **jQuery.ajax()**. That's my solution at the moment: If an timeout occurs the page will be reloaded and the script gets another chance to load the data within it's given timeframe.

**Problem**: if "get_json.php" (example below) is really not available, it will become an endless reloading-loop. 
Possible solution: adding a counter and cancel after $x reloads.

**Question 1**:
How to handle the timeout error best?

**Question 2**:
What's your recommended timeframe for a timeout and why?

**Code**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_json.php",
    timeout: 500,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {
        alert("JSON loaded: " + json);
    },
    error: function(request, status, err) {
        if (status == "timeout") {
            // timeout -> reload the page and try again
            console.log("timeout");
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            // another error occured  
            alert("error: " + request + status + err);
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why reload the entire page instead of just retrying the Ajax call?

Comment: @Juhana: do you mean $.ajax(this); ?

Comment: Well, yes, for example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it other way, you can clear interval first when timeout occured. If you use this `clearInterval()` function than you won't need to reload page. It'll stop automatically.

```
function ajax_call(){ 
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_json.php",
        timeout: 500,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json) {
            alert("JSON loaded: " + json);
        },
        error: function(request, status, err) {
            if (status == "timeout") {
                // timeout -> reload the page and try again
             clearInterval(ajax_call);
                window.location.reload(); //make it comment if you don't want to reload page
            } else {
                // another error occured  
                alert("error: " + request + status + err);
            }
        }
    });
}

setInterval(ajax_call,timeout_duration);
```