# If ajax isn't successful after an interval how do I cancel it and perform an operation?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery ajax call that looks something like this:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'mouseover', '#wp-admin-bar-noti-bar-new', function() {

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "domain.com",
    // etc
    success:function(data){

        // change element id
        jQuery('#wp-admin-bar-noti-bar-new').attr('id','wp-admin-bar-noti-bar');
    }
  });
});
```

So if ajax call is successful, it changes element. My question is, how do I make it so that if call is unsuccessful after 10 seconds, it should **cancel it** and do something (like show alert).

How can I do this?

Comment: This question and answers will help you out -> [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/446594/1407478) - `<ajax-instance>.abort()`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a `timeout` on the AJAX call and handle that error situation.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'domain.com',
    timeout: 10000, // ten seconds in milliseconds
    .
    .
    .
    error: function(request, status, err) {
        if (status === "timeout") {
            alert("Timeout");
        }
    }
});
```

*Note, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27245238/2319844), in part, to formulate my answer.*

Once AJAX requests are sent, they are sent. You can't really do too much about them on the server side (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/446625/2319844)).

**You can, however, cancel them on the client side.** The `request` parameter is an `jqXHR` object which allows you to abort the call using `request.abort();` so your function will look something like this:

```
error: function(request, status, err) {
    if (status === "timeout") {
        request.abort();
        alert("Timeout");
    }
}
```

Comment: But will this **abort** the initial ajax call?

Comment: @Musa no, I forgot to add the function parameters.

Comment: As far as I can read this code, it does handle timeout, but does it cancel the initial call?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, you really cant "abort" an ajax-request. When it is fired to the server you have no longer control of the process. But you can abort the bindings on the javascript layer.

Comment: Thank you, that is an outstanding explanation. The only problem is that I just ran your code and it does not work, see my full code here: http://pastebin.com/g7nJnPZn Did I place your code correctly? I suspect there is an error somewhere?

Comment: Sorry I did not explain this properly. Nothing is working when implementing your solution. No errors are shown but the initial ajax is never called.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson You need a comma after the end of your success function.

Comment: Dude. Outstanding. Thank you **very** much!

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Glad to be of service.

Comment: Just changing 100000 to 10000 so it's 10 seconds ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71962/discussion-between-jsve-and-henrik-petterson).